# Calender control(date class ) is not working in dialog (Jquery)

Tags: php, jquery

I have created a Dialog box with some label and textboxes inside. Whenever the dialog box opens and after clicking on Date of birth textbox it is not displaying the Calender. But the same is working in normal window other than Dialog window.

Any idea?

Plz find snapshot @

http://s8.postimg.org/3quz7gvrp/untitled.png

Comment: what console is showing? could u replicate the issue on jsfiddle or just go through this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abidmix/dBLn5/1/

Answer (score 0):

In css increase the z-index of the calendar set it to 10000
you can do it by adding below code

```
div.ui-datepicker {
z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: you are using jquery datepicker?